# How to use gulp for compress?

Tags: css, gulp

I need compress CSS and JS files without "multiple css files to one".

My IDE: PhpStorm
My Framework: Laravel 5.3

For example:

I need compress this file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/bootstrap.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/menu.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I use this code in `Gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('BootstrapCss', function () {
gulp.src('public/site/css/bootstrap.css')
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/site/dist/css'));
});
```

Is a code should be written for each file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed Answer**

You can try the `foreach` gulp module to iterate over all files and minify each separately.

```
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');

gulp.task('BootstrapCss', function () {
  gulp.src('public/site/css/*.css')
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
      return stream
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/site/dist/css'));
});
```

**Old Answer**

Just use a catch-all `*.css`. I've replaced `bootstrap.css` with `*.css` below:

```
gulp.task('BootstrapCss', function () {
gulp.src('public/site/css/*.css')
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/site/dist/css'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, No!!! this code multiple css files to one css !!! I don't convert all CSS to one CSS !

Comment: @mySun my bad - edited the answer to minify each file separately (you'll want to use the `foreach` gulp module.

Comment: In my css folder is min.css, How not convert these files into?